# synchronous method calls not working with promise - nodejs

Tags: node.js

Iam creating an http server. before creating the server i check db connection. if db is down..the check method will be called again until its connected. after this i start the server. after starting the server i need to check few configuration settings. server starts properly.  I wrote a code to call 3 configuration settings verification code one after the other using then. However 2 methods are executed simultaneously and last one is not called at all.

//to check connectivity to another app

```
function checkconfig1() {
    return request.post({
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: url,

    }, function(error, response, body) {

    if (body == 'success') {
        //config 1 is verified
        console.log("config 1 is verified")

    }
    if (error) {
        console.log("config 1 is not correct")
        return Promise.delay(2500).then(checkconfig1);
    }
});

 }
 function checkconfig2() {

return request.get({
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: url,

}, function(error, response, body) {

    if (error) {
        console.log("config 2 is not correct")
        return Promise.delay(2500).then(checkconfig2);
    } else {
        console.log("config 2 is verified")
    }

});

 }

     function checkconfig3() {
        var cmd = 'somecommand';
        return exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {

            if (error) {
                console.log("config 2 is not correct")
                return Promise.delay(2500).then(checkFonts);
            } else {
                console.log("config 2 is verified")
            }

        });
     }

 module.exports = function() {

    return checkconfg1().then(checkconfig2).then(checkconfig3());
    //return checkFonts();
 }
```

Am I doing it correctly. Can anyone explain how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote? it will be better if some explanation is given on down voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code a bit. 
Can you try this:

```
function checkconfig1() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.post({
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: url,

        }, function (error, response, body) {

            if (body == 'success') {
                //config 1 is verified
                console.log("config 1 is verified")
                return resolve();

            }
            if (error) {
                console.log("config 1 is not correct")
                return resolve(Promise.delay(2500).then(checkconfig1));
            }
        });
    });
}
function checkconfig2() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.get({
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: url,

        }, function (error, response, body) {

            if (error) {
                console.log("config 2 is not correct")
                return resolve(Promise.delay(2500).then(checkconfig2));
            } else {
                console.log("config 2 is verified")
                return resolve(response);
            }

        });

    });



}

function checkconfig3() {
    var cmd = 'somecommand';
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        exec(cmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("config 2 is not correct")
                return resolve(Promise.delay(2500).then(checkFonts));
            } else {
                console.log("config 2 is verified")
                return resolve();
            }

        });
    });
}

module.exports = function () {
    return checkconfig1().then(checkconfig2).then(checkconfig3);
    //return checkFonts();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried the solution. now it calls all the three. but again simultaneously. rather than one after the other. first config is not set so it shows error message continuously but in the start it shows all three consoles and then the error message for the first config

Comment: That's strange. Are there any other part of your application that could log the same?

Comment: No. Only here I log it

Comment: I have edited the code and that works. but not sure how it works. trying to understand the concept. anyway thanks for the solution. am accepting the answer. however please verify my edit and let me know